# access images from resource folder on iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have folder inside reource folder lets say

resource->folder A->61.png

so how to access this path I did this

```
NSString *myFilePath=   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"61" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"A" ];

NSLog(@"file is at %@",myFilePath);// its null
```

why my path is null?

Comment: Have a look inside the compiled app's bundle, is the image really inside the subfolder?

Comment: yes it is inside ,,,if i move my image outside then its working i mean without directory :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for anyone who is looking for it.

You need to import the directory into your app using the following method:

1. Create a Directory on your Mac.
2. Select to Add Existing Files to your project
3. Select the Directory you want to import
4. In the pop-up window make sure you select "Copy items into destination group's folder" and "Create Folder References for any added folders"
5. Hit "Add"

You’re done!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use inDirectory. Even if you create directory under resource folder, all resources go to a flat directory under app bundle.

```
NSString *myFilePath=   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"61" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: oh, you was a bit faster than me with this answer)) agree with taskinoor.

Comment: Resources can by copied to a subfolder of the app bundle if you add the subfolder to your xcode project as a Folder Reference.